# How to choose a preferred datacenter when calling elastic search?

Tags: elasticsearch, load-balancing

I have cluster of 4 instances of Elastic Search across two datacenters (let's say east and west zones). Elastic Search is invoked from an aggregator API which is also deployed to both east and west zones. Now how do I prevent my API at east zone always invoking the Elastic Search instances in east zone but not at the west? At the same time, I want the call to be failed over to west zone instances if east is completely down.

Comment: You're using two different terminology: data centers and availability zones. What is it that your cluster is spread across? The latter would be fine, but the former not at all.

Comment: we have two data centers.

Comment: You should never spread your cluster across two different DCs, it's bad practice. Or do you have two completely independent clusters (each having a complete copy of the data) in each DC that you feed in parallel?

Comment: Thanks Val for quick response! I'm just trying to architect this. It's not yet existing. So it's a good practice to have one cluster for each DC? How do I take care of failover if first DC goes down completely? Looking for some advise / articles on how to architect production elastic search clusters with multiple DCs.

Comment: I would start with this: https://www.elastic.co/blog/clustering_across_multiple_data_centers